# Are the flashing instructions on the Ubuntu website safe for Nexus 10?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, android, nexus-7, nexus-10

I realize that the site says only the Nexus 4 and Samsung Galaxy Nexus are supported, but I am wondering if it is "safe" to follow these same directions on a Nexus 10?

http://www.ubuntu.com/phone/install

Or do I still have to follow the instructions on this site?

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Install

TIA

Answer (score 1):

The instructions on the wiki are more updated, so you should go with what you see there (the second link you posted). Be warned, however, that Ubuntu Touch is still considered a work in progress, and could potentially brick your device.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that later and post how it goes. I'll be ok, today's bricked device is tonight's backyard bb gun target practice after a few mourning beers ;). If it doesn't run Ubuntu, I don't want it anyways.

Comment: Okay, good luck!

Answer (score 0):

NO, the Nexus 10 is NOT supported at present, and the Nexus 7 (2012 edition) only with restrictions. The MIR display server still does not work on these devices.

Canonical's development priority is clearly on the phones rather than the tablets.